# Scala Cats Pure on List with Multiple Items

Tags: scala, scala-cats

With cats library. I can easily do

```
1.pure[List]
```

but how do I do create a list with multiple items using pure?

Comment: Is the goal to create a list with multiple items, or to use pure to create the list? Because List(1,2,3) will create a list with multiple items.

Comment: use pure to create a list with multiple items. just want to know if its possible.

Comment: In that case, no, I don't believe its possible.

Comment: def pure[A](x: A): List[A] = x :: Nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monad `M` must obey some laws. One of them is

```
pure[M](x).flatMap(f) = f(x)
```

for arbitrary functions `f: A -> M[A]`.

With the common implementation of `List.flatMap`, this leaves not much room for different implementations of `pure[List]`.